# Edit distance - dynamic approach

Tags: c++

I have to code edit distance with dynamic programming approach, and I don't understand why, with my code, for the strings "short" and "ports", my output is 2 when I should have 3 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

int edit_distance(const string &str1, const string &str2) {
    if(str1 == str2) return 0;
    int n = str1.length() +1;
    int m = str2.length() +1;
    vector<vector<int>> D(n); // Matrix that will contain all the calculation
    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){ // Resizing of the matrix
        D[i].resize(m);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) //Initialisation
        D[i][0] = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) //Initialisation
        D[0][j] = j;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        for(int j = 1; j < m; ++j){
            if(str1[i] != str2[j]) // if str1[i] != str2[j], then take the minimum of the case of deletion, insertion, mismatch
                D[i][j] = std::min({D[i-1][j]+1, D[i][j-1]+1, D[i-1][j-1]+1});
            else if(str1[i] == str2[j]) // if str1[i] == str2[j], then take the minimum of the case of deletion, insertion, match
                D[i][j] = std::min({D[i-1][j]+1, D[i][j-1]+1, D[i-1][j-1]});
            }
        }
    return D[n-1][m-1]; //retourner le résultat voulu
}
```

Comment: [How to Debug a Small Program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) would help. Check your program step by step.

Comment: I certainly have a problem for the double loop for, but I don't see what, and I checked for a long time

Comment: The quickest way to get an answer, is get a rubber dock and write your logic in comment and try to explain it. Then people "might" spot on the difference between your logic and implementation. Rather than read and guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: First, fill `D` manually on a piece of paper, check that `D[n-1][m-1]` is indeed correct. Then use a debugger to find where the discrepancy occurs for the first time.

Comment: If you do not understand the result of your program, then you should add output of intermediate results. E.g. output all the changes which your program outputs. Maybe the program just found a shorter way to change A into B than you.... For example if "move one character" is 1 and "replace one character" is 2. Then I agree with your program.

Comment: Please explain in detail why you expect the result 3 for "short" -> "ports". Then compare it to the debugging result of how your program arrived at "2".

Comment: Please explain the definition of "edit distance" used for determining the desired result "3".  It might help finding where your implementation diverges.

Comment: I have put comment @LouisGo. Otherwise I tried to implement this pseudo code : https://www.noelshack.com/2020-35-4-1598509149-capture-d-ecran-de-2020-08-27-08-18-50.png

Comment: Your code does not seem to correspond exactly to the pseudo code in the link. Check the indices.

Comment: Note: this corresponds to the *Levenshtein distance*. Details and pseudo-code can be found on Wikipedia, *Edit distance* entry (better reference than your link).

Comment: Thanks, I checked this, and for me I do exactly the same code as this one : https://www.noelshack.com/2020-35-4-1598516162-capture-d-ecran-de-2020-08-27-10-15-47.png, I just put n = str1.length() +1, so that the for loop goes from 1 to str1.length, same for str2. @Damien

Comment: For example, it should be `if(str1[i-1] != str2[j-1])`  and not `if(str1[i] != str2[j])`

Comment: Thank you very very much ! I wouldn't see it before a loooong time !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
The strings indices didn't match the distance matrix indices.
Even though you added one to `str1` & `str2`, the first char in each of the string will start from 0 and not from 1.
You can prepend a matching char to both strings to fix that (make sure you remove `const` in the function's parameters)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

int edit_distance(string& str1, string& str2) { // remove const
    if (str1 == str2) return 0;

    // adding a match prefix to start from 0
    str1.insert(0, " "); 
    str2.insert(0, " ");

    // the strings length is correspondly incremented
    int n = str1.length();
    int m = str2.length();

    vector<vector<int>> D(n); // Matrix that will contain all the calculation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // Resizing of the matrix
        D[i].resize(m);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) //Initialisation
        D[i][0] = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) //Initialisation
        D[0][j] = j;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < m; ++j) {
            if (str1[i] != str2[j]) // if str1[i] != str2[j], then take the minimum of the case of deletion, insertion, mismatch
                D[i][j] = std::min({ D[i - 1][j] + 1, D[i][j - 1] + 1, D[i - 1][j - 1] + 1 });
            else if (str1[i] == str2[j]) // if str1[i] == str2[j], then take the minimum of the case of deletion, insertion, match
                D[i][j] = std::min({ D[i - 1][j] + 1, D[i][j - 1] + 1, D[i - 1][j - 1] });
        }
    }
    return D[n - 1][m - 1]; //retourner le résultat voulu
}
```